# Display a dynamically changing arrayList of objects with 4 string fields

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would assume that I should use a jTable. I tried this, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to append, insert and delete rows without a ton of overrides and complicated code. I find it hard to believe that Oracle doesn't have an easier way to do it.

Here's the premise. I have a few arrayLists. Each contain n amount of items and I want to be able to add these items' properties in the form of strings to the jtable and once i surpass a certain number of rows, I want the jTable to scroll.

So that's the reason I need to be able to add and remove rows.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in [*How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), [`DefaultTableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) has convenient methods to add, insert and remove rows. Simply update your model using any of these methods and your view will be updated accordingly.

Addendum: There's an example [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/AppendRow.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GlazedLists](http://glazedlists.com). It makes working with dynamically changing data and sowing it in JTables/JLists/JTrees, etc, very simple.